# MobilenetSSDv2 freeze on transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am training a model using Mobilenet-SSD-v2, it trains for some time, then tries to evaluate, and freezes.

I am running tensorflow-gpu 1.14, inside the `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` docker image. I am using an RTX 2060 on ubuntu 19.04. I am using the latest object detection API from this git repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/models.

I've tried to set throttle_secs in model_lib.py, it didn't do anything. I can still trains, but everytime it tries to evaulate, I need to restart the docker container.

I am using only the code provided by the git repo. I start the training using the command below.

```
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=/tensorflow/models/research/face/pipeline.config
MODEL_DIR=/tensorflow/models/research/face/training/
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=50000
SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1
python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES \
    --alsologtostderr
```

I expected it to continue training. But instead I just get stuck and need to restart.

```
I1002 18:28:30.106040 139663203059520 evaluation.py:255] Starting evaluation at 2019-10-02T18:28:30Z
I1002 18:28:30.717183 139663203059520 monitored_session.py:240] Graph was finalized.
2019-10-02 18:28:30.717937: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718182: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce RTX 2060 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.71
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718232: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718251: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718263: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718279: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718309: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718326: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718401: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718655: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718861: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718888: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718898: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718907: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2019-10-02 18:28:30.718992: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-10-02 18:28:30.719242: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-10-02 18:28:30.719460: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4946 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
I1002 18:28:30.720419 139663203059520 saver.py:1280] Restoring parameters from /tensorflow/models/research/face/training/model.ckpt-10756
I1002 18:28:32.285661 139663203059520 session_manager.py:500] Running local_init_op.
I1002 18:28:32.408489 139663203059520 session_manager.py:502] Done running local_init_op.
```

Comment: Is it stopping after few iterations? Like in 100 to 500?

Comment: Around 600 iterations, then it freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced **the same issue** like 6-7 months ago and couldn't able to found a solution. However, I tried to create a new environment from scratch. The details of my **working** environment is listed below.

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2018.8.24                py35_1    anaconda
contextlib2               0.5.5                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cython                    0.29.13                  pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
html5lib                  0.9999999                pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
libprotobuf               3.6.0                h1a1b453_0    anaconda
lxml                      4.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.1.1.26                 pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    0.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    6.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.2.3                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.5.6                he025d50_0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.2                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                41.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.1                 h21ff451_3    anaconda
vs2015_runtime            15.5.2                        3    anaconda
werkzeug                  0.15.6                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.33.6                   pypi_0    pypi
wincertstore              0.2              py35hfebbdb8_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_3    anaconda
```

**NOTE:**

You can distinguish that my python version is 3.5, this is my home pc. My work-pc has exactly the same packages along with python 3.6.8. So this also works with 3.6 as well.

Furthermore, I believe that `tensorflow/models` are some kind of working with the previous versions of tensorflow, mine is 1.8.0 as you can see. I was using 1.13 when I experienced the same issue.

I hope it would resolve.